# PHP increment string value each iteration

Tags: php

I want to increment the int on the end of my string which together makes up the complete value.

```
$btnid = 'btnid1';

 for($i = 1; $i < $countP; $i++) {
     $btnid = 'btnid' . ++;
 }
```

I tried different types of concatenation but I can't seem to get it to work if I just set it to `1` it works but I need the string there too.

Answer (score 2):

Just append `$i` to the string `btnid` in each loop iteration.

```
$string = 'btnid';
for($i = 1; $i < $countP; $i++) {
     $btnid   = $string . $i;
}
```

Comment: Oh yeah of course thanks, I was just trying to over complicate it

Comment: My update is even simpler and reflects the update to your question

Answer (score 0):

As a side note (and seriously, **DO NOT** actually do this) so long as you don't go past btnid9, you can just increment the string.

```
$btnid = 'btnid1';
for($i = 1; $i < 9; $i++) {
    $btnid++;
}
echo $btnid; // btnid9
```

If you go over, things get a bit weird:

```
$btnid++;
echo $btnid; // btnie0
```

Manual page: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.increment.php